# PrimeFaces has changed the way we refer the widget variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces has changed the way we refer the widget variable.

- PrimeFaces 3.2 `widgetVar.show()`
- PrimeFaces 5.x `PF('widgetVar').show()`

I am migrating one project from PrimeFaces 3 to PrimeFaces 5.2. 
Is there any quick fix for this change instead of changing it in all the XHTML pages?

Comment: The 'answer' is valid, although there is a good reason the 'old' way was changed to the new way (as can be read in the answer). Best way imo is to bite the apple and use some intelligent regex search/replace with grouping. Should, even with up to lets say a 100 pages not take more than one or two hours. And it is PrimeFaces btw, not Prime Faces ;-)

Comment: Thanks, replaced in all the xhtmls, but the context param is useful in case if we miss at any place.

Answer (score 4):

> #### Legacy Widget Namespace
>
> In 4.0, `widgetVar.method()` usage to access the client side api of a component has been deprecated in favor of `PF(‘widgetVar’).show()` to keep the window scope clean. It seems not everyone has migrated to `PF(‘…’)` in 4.x and upon requests of two PRO users, we have added a context parameter to bring window scope back. Please note that `PF(‘…’)` is always on, following configuration also enables access from window scope as before (`widgetVar.method()`).
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>primefaces.LEGACY_WIDGET_NAMESPACE</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

Source: [Primefaces blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3184), [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=LEGACY_WIDGET_NAMESPACE)

Comment: A valid (and upvoted by me) answer. Although I'd personally suggest to 'bite the apple' ;-)

Comment: Thanks I did bite ;)